# Missing icons in Krita

Tags: 14.04, unity, icons

I installed Krita on Ubuntu 14.04, Unity desktop, and the icons are missing:

> [image]

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Maybe are you using the latest stable version? Instructions here: https://krita.org/download/krita-desktop/

Comment: @Kassius That's exactly how I installed Krita.

Comment: I think you already tried: http://forum.pisilinuxworld.org/index.php?topic=356.0

Comment: @Kassius Seems to be the same issue, however I cannot install `icon-theme-oxygen*` or `gtk3-...` (*Unable to locate package*).

Comment: Sorry, the package is called oxygen-icon-theme in Ubuntu please try: `sudo apt-get install oxygen-icon-theme`. If it is already installed, try reinstalling `sudo apt-get install --reinstall oxygen-icon-theme`

Comment: @Kassius That's the solution. Don't forget to add an answer. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have this issue, as seen here ([No icons in Krita](http://forum.pisilinuxworld.org/index.php?topic=356.0))

Please install the package `oxygen-icon-theme`, enter this command in the terminal:

`sudo apt-get install oxygen-icon-theme`

If it is already installed, try reinstalling with this command:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall oxygen-icon-theme`